# Validate route data on every request in ASP.Net Core Net 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently migrating an ASP.Net MVC 6 app to Core Net6. In addition to the default Controller/Action/Id route, I'm creating an additional route that contains a customerkey in the URL:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "ManagingCustomer",
     pattern: "{customerkey:int}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "Default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Within the app, a user can manage their own account or other accounts to which they have access. When they are managing an account other than their own, I would navigate with the prepended customerkey route data.

If a URL contains the customerkey route data item, where in the pipeline can I inject code to validate that the currently authenticated user actually has access to the requested account? I would like this run on every request and don't necessarily want to add code to every controller and action in order to support it. In the old MVC6 app, I would have done this in global.asax.cs. I just don't know where this fits in the core world. I'm guessing it falls into middleware? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can look into this thread. Here I have answered a similar question, you can create an action filter and register globally. In that answer I have also explained to add a custom attribute on the action that I guess is not needed in your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121543/how-to-check-something-before-execute-http-request-aspnet-core-web-api-6/74122609#74122609

Answer (score 0):

If you already registed authoriztion policies ,i think you could try as below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "ManageCustomer",
                    pattern: "somesection/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization("Policyname");
                .......
            });
```

And maybe you could try with Fallbackpolicy as this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1#require-authenticated-users-1):

If you just want to get the customerkey and validate it in your middleware,you could try as below:

```
app.Use(
            async (context, next) =>
            {
                
                var routevalue = context.Request.RouteValues;
                var customerkey = routevalue.ContainsKey("customerkey") ? routevalue["customerkey"].ToString() : "";
                //add your logical here
                if (customerkey != "")
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("ErrorInfo");
            });
```